# Using a different internal (target) port in a WordPress image other than 80

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm looking for a way to use an internal port other than 80. I've searched everywhere with no result. My config is simple:

```
... maria DB stuff...

mywordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      # I want this to be 8181:8181 (or anything else that isn't 80)
      - 8181:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mywordpress:8181');
    volumes:
      - ../../:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
```

When I try to use ports as  `- 8181:8181` WordPress is not accessible internally anymore on `http://mywordpress:8181`

The reason for this that I have a database backup with hardcoded `'http://mywordpress:8181'` and I want to run the internal WordPress container under the same port to prevent doing find-replace on the database or the likes.

Is this possible using this image? I was looking into implementing a reverse proxy, or maybe modifying the apache config. I'm not the best at Docker so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and the Dockerfile?

Comment: Right my bad. Dockerfile is not relevant here, it just creates an extra folder. I removed the `build` and added the image in the docker compose code in my question now

Comment: You will have to extend the `wordpress:latest` image yourself and modify the ports the embeded apache listens on inside the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file (to see content => `docker run --rm wordpress:latest cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf`). This is not a feature proposed by the official image. And quite frankly, I really don't see the interest of changing this in a docker(-compose) scenario. If you want to implement a reverse proxy, just do it in an other container: it will be able to call whatever backend running on whatever container on whatever port.

Comment: If you want to play around with that image, I suggest you get one of the `*-fpm` flavored image and plug it to a webserver running in an other container (either apache or nginx for even more performance gain). Going from php as a module in the embeded apache in the `latest` image to a fact-cgi implementation should significantly lower the global wordpress footprint (and ease scalability if this is one of your requirement).

Comment: @Zeitounator so if I modify the Apache config and add port `8282` for example, then I can modify the ports in the composer file and have Apache pick it up? `port: - 8282:8282`?

My setup is made to run only on CI for testing purposes, so I don't care about performance, just simplicity

Comment: @Zeitounator your suggestion was correct. Thank you. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Setting up a webserver inside a very specific docker image is a bit off topic on SO.